# Transfer function of mathematical model

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Im trying to derive a transfer function from by books end of the chapter exercise, but i can in no way match it with the given solution(given by our instructor). I was hoping if you can explain me from where did the red portion of the numerator comes I could match it till the denominator, i have attached the pictures.

[mathematical model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Q3F.jpg)

[answer and the problem in the red portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S42Xi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I get $K$ for the numerator rather than what's given in the solution, although I don't know what the symbols mean so this could well be equivalent.